Get access token for a Google Cloud API
I can easily get access tokens (valid only for 1 hour) that are needed to use Google Cloud API's by running the gcloud command line tool:
./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud auth application-default print-access-token

However, I need to get access tokens from my Node.js and Flutter apps. And there I am unable to do so, because the required information includes cliendID and clientSecret (which I have) but also refreshToken (which I don't). In fact, even if I could get a refreshToken, that also periodically expires. What to do? How do I get access to Google Cloud API's from my apps?
UPDATE: here's how to do this in Node.js:
const { GoogleAuth } = require('google-auth-library');

async function getAccessToken() {
    const auth = new GoogleAuth({
        keyFilename: 'path/to/your/service-account-key.json',
        scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
    });

    const client = await auth.getClient();
    const accessToken = await client.getAccessToken();
    return accessToken;
}

But I still can't figure out how to do this in Dart/Flutter...

Try the Google cloud node js client library it may not be well documented through.

Yes, in node.js there's a way. Thank you. Flutter appears to be really hosed though.

Using a service account key is rarely a solution
Your frontend can't access directly a Google API. the correct pattern is the following:
frontend (flutter?) -> Backend (Node on Cloud Run?) -> Google API
In that pattern, you use the Backend service account to generate an access token thanks to the metadata server (and not a service account key).
Now the question is: does the backend access is public or private? It depends on your use case. If it requires authentication, you can use Cloud Identity (or firebase auth)

Yes, that's what it's shaping out to look like.  I am able to get the access token via my Node.js server; see the script in my original post.

Yes, and your script use a service account key file which is a bad practice (as long as your nodejs run on Google Cloud).But if  you implemented the pattern I share, where is your issue?

My Node.js code is not on Google cloud and is on a separate server. I http.get from my Flutter app to my Node.js code which in turn gets the accessToken from Google API and returns it to the Flutter app.  Would you recommend a better way?

Of course I could also do the entire processing in my Node.js code and just pass end-user inputs and outputs between Flutter and Node.js codes.

The problem is: if you expose the access token to your flutter app, running on your user device, it's super easy to intercept it and to use it for anything that you don't control. That's why it's better to have a backend layer that control inputs, and then which call the API(s) to get the relevant data and send them back to the user.

For security reason (and service account key file issue), where are you running your NodeJS code? And why not on Cloud Run?

Yes, if you intercept the access token, then it's a problem. I agree that it's best to do processing on the server side and just return the final results.
